# ¿Como crear un hash como este hecho en Node.js pero en php?

Tags: php, nodejs, hash

Como crear un hash como este hecho en Node.js pero en php.

`const bdHash = criptoHub.sha256(stringToHash, KEY);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP posee una función nativa: [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.hash.php)

`hash ("algoritmo_a_usar", $datos, [true / false])`

Si el tercer parámetro es omitido, ya que es opcional (de ahí los corchetes), se asumirá que es `false`, que la función interpretará como que la salida ha de ser en hexadecimal. Si se especifica `true`, la salida del hash será en binario sin formato

Para una lista de los algoritmos soportados, puedes hacer

```
<?php
    print_r(hash_algos());
?>
```